# How to compare timestamps in Ruby

Tags: ruby

What is the  simplest way to achieve this in Ruby?

I have two strings:

```
a = "08:02:04.982"
b = "10:07:12.004"
```

I need to convert each string to a date object then compare to ensure that `b` is greater (later) than `a`. Such as:

```
if b > a
  print "this is normal"
else 
  print "this is not normal"
end
```

I tried using:

```
Time.parse("08:02:04.982")
```

but that insisted on returning a date.

So I tried:

```
Time.parse("08:02:04.982", "%H:%M:%S.%3N")
```

but that complains about undefined method "year".

Comment: Why do you want to compare its time representations? Their string representations return the same result: `a < b #=> true` and `b < a #=> false`

Comment: You want `strptime`, not `parse`

Comment: Wow! Ruby string comparison is casting the string value to a time type and comparing that behind the scenes? That's great! Thank you!

Comment: No, it's not, it's doing a string comparison, but that still works as long as you keep to fixed number of digits for each component.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like I can, as spickermann suggests just compare the strings and get what I need. Doing it this way actually saves me converting  back to strings again too. Thanks very much!

Comment: @SteveTurczyn: Fixed number of digits, and a 24-hour format. It's hard to say whether OP can rely on both those, since we don't know where those strings come from.

Comment: @user3202399 what if `a = "23:00"` and `b = "01:00"`, do you consider them to be 2 hours apart (b > a) or 22 hours (a > b)?

Answer (score -4):

Meditate on this:

```
require 'time'

TIME_FORMAT = '%H:%M:%S.%n'

a = "08:02:04.982"
b = "10:07:12.004"

a_time = Time.strptime(a, TIME_FORMAT) # => 2017-06-04 08:02:04 -0700
b_time = Time.strptime(b, TIME_FORMAT) # => 2017-06-04 10:07:12 -0700

a_time < b_time # => true
a_time > b_time# => false
a_time <=> b_time # => -1
```

Without a date component comparing Time values is risky. It's hard to know whether the times are occurring in the same day. Time will supply the current "today" if it doesn't see that information, but it can be a bug if you aren't sure if the date would be the same.

As you found, you can compare two equally formatted strings without converting them to Time or DateTime objects:

```
a < b   # => true
a > b   # => false
a <=> b # => -1
```

You have to be careful though, because if you received a time string that didn't have a leading zero in any column then your comparison would be wrong, whereas, with parsing to the object it'd test correctly:

```
"8:2:4.982" == "08:02:04.982"  # => false
Time.strptime("8:2:4.982",    TIME_FORMAT) # => 2017-06-04 08:02:04 -0700
Time.strptime("08:02:04.982", TIME_FORMAT) # => 2017-06-04 08:02:04 -0700
```

(And, yes, it's very possible you could get dates and times without leading zeros. In the wilds of the internet all sorts of crazy things happen.)

---

> I tried using:

```
Time.parse("08:02:04.982")
```

> but that insisted on returning a date.

Um... no:

```
Time.parse("08:02:04.982").class # => Time
Time.parse("08:02:04.982") # => 2017-06-04 08:02:04 -0700
```

Don't rely on `parse` unless you know the LOCALE of the incoming date/datetime strings. You can research why. Instead, if the strings are in a consistent form define your own format string. It'll be faster and more reliable.